# Double click row in datagridview and get value of specific cell and pass it to another form

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

I just want to know if this below scenario is correct

I am trying to the following
1- from `MyDataGridView1` in `Form1` on duoble click on `MyDataGridView1` row I am getting value of specific column and pass it to `FORM2`

2- assign that value to `Textbox` on `Form2`

below event to get ti ID from `datagridview`

```
private void MyDataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
       vID = MyDataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

       this.Close();
       Form2 NewForm = new Form2();
       NewForm.Show();
    }
```

then save the value to

```
public static string vID ;
```

no Form2

```
Textboxid.Text = F0103.vID ;
```

at line below I am trying to lunch the leave event of `textbox` but it is not working is there any idea to lunch leave event

```
BTN_Refresh.Focus();
```

Comment: Assuming `vID` is getting the object correctly, You should add an overload representative of that datatype in the constructor of Form2. Then just pass it like `Form2 NewForm = new Form2(vID);`. It also might be better to `this.Close()` after passing the argument.

Comment: @DavidBentley please would mind to post an answer with example please

Answer (score 3):

A complete answer:

Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<Stuff> stuff = new List<Stuff>();
        stuff.Add(new Stuff() { Foo = "Foo1", Bar = "Bar1", Data = "Data1" });
        stuff.Add(new Stuff() { Foo = "Foo2", Bar = "Bar2", Data = "Data2" });

        var bindingList = new BindingList<Stuff>(stuff);
        var source = new BindingSource(bindingList, null);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        string arg = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

        Form2 form2 = new Form2(arg);
        form2.Show();

        this.Hide();
    }
}

public class Stuff
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

Form2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2(string arg)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        label1.Text = arg;
    }
}
```

One thing about winforms(and why I use WPF instead) is it overly complicates this stuff. From my testing, `this.Close()` closed down the entire app and I had to use `this.Hide()` instead.

Also, it is good to get in the habit of passing arguments instead of setting global variables. Almost anything in C# can be passed as an argument in someway and it makes for better and cleaner code.

Comment: thanks i will try it but one last thing after all that process the value assigned to 'textbox' on that `textbox` there is `leave` event how can lunch that event ?

Comment: can vID be null ? `Form2 NewForm = new Form2(vID);` because I am not always going to pass this value sometimes this value could be null

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly.  You can pass the string to your Form2 constructor.

```
private void MyDataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  vID = MyDataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

  Form2 NewForm = new Form2(vID);

  this.Close();

  NewForm.Show();
}
```

Then in the constructor, set the `TextBox` text to this string.

```
public class Form2
{
  public Form2(string vid)
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    Textboxid.Text = vid;
  }
}
```

Comment: can vID be null ? `Form2 NewForm = new Form2(vID);` because I am not always going to pass this value sometimes this value could be null